# Cannot disable SSLv3 on Amazon Linux Instance

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using SSL Certificate issued by Go Daddy. 
On my Linux Instance following are the software details :-

- Apache Version  - Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon)
- Openssl Version - OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
- mod_ssl version - mod_ssl-2.4.2

**Note :- I install Apache from RPM Package and later I install mod_ssl and openssl from rpm package.**

1) The problem is when I disable SSLv3 and test SSL Server from  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ it gives me warning that **"this server does not support TLSv1.2 which is current best"** and when I enable TLSv1.2 protocol the same test warns me about **"This server supports SSLv3 protocol and vulnerable to Poodle attack"** 
How to disable SSLv3 and enable TLSv1.2 at same time on server?
Current configuration of my Vhost file about SSL is:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
```

2) I cannot create a Strong Diffie-Hellman Group. Current is 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman group and want to create 2048-bit group for the site. 
I issue this command to generate 2048-bit key:-

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
```

and my configuration in VHost is:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters /etc/httpd/dhparams.pem
```

when I restart server error message pop up:

```
Invalid command 'SSLOpenSSLConfCmd', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How to resolve this issue?

Output of command `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_2 -msg` when SSLv3 is enabled :-

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0138], ClientHello

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 003a], ServerHello

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 12a7], Certificate

depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2     
Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 020f], ServerKeyExchange

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0004], ServerHelloDone

>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0086], ClientKeyExchange

>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]

>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00ca]???

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
```

output of command `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -ssl3 -msg` with SSLv3 disabled :-

```
>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> SSL 3.0 Handshake [length 0099], ClientHello

<<< ??? [length 0005]

<<< SSL 3.0 Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
```

Output of command `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_2 -msg` when SSLv3 is disabled :-

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0138], ClientHello

<<< ??? [length 0005]

>>> ??? [length 0005]

>>> TLS 1.0 Alert [length 0002], fatal protocol_version
```

SSL Debug Error Logs in Apache for command `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_2 -msg` when SSLv3 is disabled :-

```
[Tue Nov 24 07:50:13.019993 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 6419] [client 127.0.0.1:32836] AH01964: Connection to child 2 established (server site1.example.com:443)
[Tue Nov 24 07:50:13.023693 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 6419] [client 127.0.0.1:32836] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server site1.example.com:443)
[Tue Nov 24 07:50:13.023752 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 6419] SSL Library Error: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version (SSL alert number 70)
[Tue Nov 24 07:50:13.023789 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 6419] [client 127.0.0.1:32836] AH01998: Connection closed to child 2 with abortive shutdown (server site1.example.com:443)
```

[image: Openssl Version info On system]

`sslscan --no-failed "site1.domain.com"` command result when `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` is used in configuration:-

[image: SSLScan Result]

`sslscan --no-failed "site1.domain.com"` command result when `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` is not used in configuration:-

[image: SSLScan Result]

Both the results shows no sign of TLSv1.2 protocol.
I think sslscan only scan for SSLv3 and TLSv1.1 protocol. Not TLSv1.2
Now when I tested this result on [SSLLab](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) with `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` is not used in configuration then :-

[image: SSLLab]

It says TLSv1.2 is enable.

Comment: From https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html (Common Server Products > Apache > DH Parameters): in some Apache versions, you need to append your DH parameters to your certificate, and the execute `service apache2 reload`.

Comment: I tied that also, but not working.

Comment: locally, can you try to establish a connection with `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:<SSLport> -ssl3` ?

Comment: I disabled the SSLv3 in my configuration and I cannot establish a connection with SSLv3. Its working. But I also cannot establish connection with TLSv1.2.  

    `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:<SSLport> -tls1_2` 

I want to setup a secure connection on TLSv1.2.

Comment: Ok, to be sure I understand correctly: with SSL3 enabled, you manage to connect in TLS1.2 ?

Comment: yes. And I don't want that. I want to disable SSLv3 and enable TLSv1.2 at same time.

Comment: Easily understandable, I just wanted to make sure we were on the same page. With the same configuration you use I manage to have TLS1.2. Have you tried TLS1.2 without custom DH params ?

Comment: Yes I tired that also. Commented out `SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters /etc/httpd/dhparams.pem` directive but not working.

Comment: Can this issue occur due to mod_ssl package. Because the time I Install Apache I don't have mod_ssl package. Later I manually compile mod_ssl package.

Comment: Yeah maybe. Did you not add the mod_ssl through _a2enmod_ ? But your tests clearly show that TLS1.2 **can** be enabled, so your mod_ssl supports it. When DHParams and with/without SSL3, can you run `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:<ssl_port> -tsl1_2 -msg` and then update your question with the messages beginning by '>>>' and '<<<' ?

Comment: Please strip the hex bytes ;) and can you also do it with ssl3 disabled ?

Comment: One more thing, I am running two websites on single instance as NameBaseVhost in apache. Both the sites have different CA Sign Certificate.

Comment: It's funny because in the last one, you clearly see that the handshake is aborted by the client. If TLS1.2 wasn't enabled, it would have been aborted by the server. I'll look more into it today ;)

Comment: is your website currently running no SSL3 ?

Comment: SSL3 on my website is enable.
The Error in Logs I can see is 

    `protocol_version (70) :-
 
    "The protocol version the client attempted to negotiate is recognized,  but not supported. For example, old protocol versions might be avoided for security reasons. This message is always fatal."`

This error occurs when SSL3 is disabled.

Comment: Are you sure your OpenSSL version information is correct? Amazon versions look more like "openssl-1.0.1k-10.86.amzn1." It seems Amazon (and others) make their own bastardized versions by backporting security fixes. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179977.

Comment: @RichardBrightwell I have updated my question with openssl version info.

Answer (score 1):

Add this below line & check
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2

Comment: `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2 ` gives me error when restarting apache. SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'

Comment: run this command sslscan --no-failed "your.hostname" this will give you the current status, So that we can understand what is currently running.

Comment: Check this link < http://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-prevent-poodle-attacks-on-aws-elb-and-cloudfront/ > for reference
You may find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this link but  I am not using any loadbalancer or AWS ELB service. I am using a single Instance and on that 2 websites are running

Comment: I assume that you have restarted the service & clear the browser cache

Comment: yes I restarted the service, cleared browser cache nothing is working. I don't understand what's happening. I think i need to check same configuration with other Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

Along with SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
 
Edit the following "SSLCipherSuite" in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf.

from: SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5 to: 
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \ EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \ EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS

Comment: When I try above configuration it gives me error
     `SSL FIPS mode disabled`
      `Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers`
     `SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match`

Comment: Ok. Try this cipher: SSLCipherSuite EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \ EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \ EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS

Comment: Correction: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK